# Get all objects from database that are not in a relationship yet

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have the following query and it's doing it's job fine:

```sql
SELECT exams.id, exams.date FROM exams
WHERE exams.modul_id = (SELECT questions.modul_id FROM questions where questions.id = 5)
      AND NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM exam_question, questions
          WHERE questions.id = 5
              AND questions.id = exam_question.question_id
              AND exam_question.exam_id = exams.id
      )
```

It returns me all exams that belong to the same model as exam but not connteced to exam yet.

I want to use this query in Laravel but I always get an empty result back (it shouldn't be empty)

```php
DB::table('exams')
->select(['id', 'date'])
->whereRaw('modul_id = '.$question->modul_id)
->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($question) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('questions as q')
        ->join('exam_question as eq', 'q.id', '=', 'eq.question_id')
        ->join('exams as e', 'eq.exam_id', '=', 'e.id')
        ->whereRaw('q.id = '.$question->id);
})
->get();
```

The output of the laravel expression is:

```
select `id`, `date` from `exams` where modul_id = 1 and not exists (select 1 from `questions` as `q` inner join `exam_question` as `eq` on `q`.`id` = `eq`.`question_id` inner join `exams` as `e` on `eq`.`exam_id` = `e`.`id` where q.id = 5)
```

Comment: try to dump DB::table( .... ->toSql() to see final query which you build

Answer (score 0):

I see problem in your sql query dump in section `and not exists (...` you select starts with `select 1 from` it will always select number 1 from your table according to selected rows count

```
select `id`, `date` from `exams` 
where modul_id = 1 
and not exists (
    select 1 from `questions` as `q` 
    inner join `exam_question` as `eq` on `q`.`id` = `eq`.`question_id`        
    inner join `exams` as `e` on `eq`.`exam_id` = `e`.`id` where q.id = 5)
```

You have to use in query builder instead `$query->select(DB::raw(1)) ...` -> `$query->select('*') ...`

```
DB::table('exams')
->select(['id', 'date'])
->whereRaw('modul_id = '.$question->modul_id)
->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($question) {
    $query->select('*')
        ->from('questions as q')
        ->join('exam_question as eq', 'q.id', '=', 'eq.question_id')
        ->join('exams as e', 'eq.exam_id', '=', 'e.id')
        ->whereRaw('q.id = '.$question->id);
})
->get();
```

If the rest logic which you used to create your query is correct it will start to work

Comment: still no result, but you are right, I have to use the `*`